# Ordenar Tabela vinda do MySql por ordem crescente, decrescente de acordo com a selecao

Tags: php, javascript

Boa Tarde Pessoal, eu tenho uma tabela que pega os dados da minha base de dados `mysql - wamp`, entao, estou procurando alguma forma, seja por `js` ou `php` de ordenar esses dados a partir de como a pessoa decidir o modo de ordenamento da tabela, alguem poderia me ajudar?

Abaixo o codigo

```
<?php
 $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tc4','root',''); // On indique au code où est-ce que ce trouve la base de données qu'il doit remplir

 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
    { //Ici le code va chercher à afficher dans les colonnes "Ecurie" etc... ce qu'il "voit" dans la base de données que l'on a au préalable remplie
     $dbh->query("INSERT INTO f1ecuries SET ".
     "Ecurie=".$dbh->quote($_POST['Ecurie']).",".
     "Pays=".$dbh->quote($_POST['Pays']).",".
     "Annee=".$dbh->quote($_POST['Annee']).",".
     "NombredeGPs=".$dbh->quote($_POST['NombredeGPs']).",".
     "NombredeVictoires=".$dbh->quote($_POST['NombredeVictoires']).",".
     "NombredePodiums=".$dbh->quote($_POST['NombredePodiums']).",".
     "NombreTitresConstructeurs=".$dbh->quote($_POST['NombreTitresConstructeurs']).",".
     "DirecteurTechnique=".$dbh->quote($_POST['DirecteurTechnique']).",".
     "Pilote1=".$dbh->quote($_POST['Pilote1']).",".
     "Pilote2=".$dbh->quote($_POST['Pilote2']).";");
    }?>
```

Tabela

```
 <table> <!-- C'est ici que l'on créé les colonnes de la base de données -->
                            <tr><th>Ecurie</th><th>Pays</th><th>Année</th><th>Nombre de GPs</th><th>Nombre de Victoires</th>
                            <th>Nombre de Podiums</th><th>Nombre de Titres Constructeurs</th><th>Directeur Technique</th><th>Pilote 1</th><th>Pilote 2</th></tr>
                            <?php
                             $r = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM f1ecuries");
                             foreach( $r as $a )
                             {
                             echo '<tr><td>'.$a['Ecurie'].'</td>'.
                             '<td>'.$a['Pays'].'</td>'.
                             '<td>'.$a['Annee'].'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$a['NombredeGPs'].'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$a['NombredeVictoires'].'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$a['NombredePodiums'].'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$a['NombreTitresConstructeurs'].'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$a['DirecteurTechnique'].'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$a['Pilote1'].'</td>'.
                         '<td>'.$a['Pilote2'].'</td></tr>';
                         }
                        ?>
                    </table>
```

Comment: Um GET resolveria! Cria links com o filtro que você deseja depois aplica esse GET no ORDER BY.

Comment: muitoobrigado veio, vo tentar fazendo isso